What is the meaning of "otherwise" in the following sentence?
What is the meaning of "otherwise" in the following sentences?
(Source : https://www.wdef.com/tennessee-bill-seeks-to-ban-chemical-based-weather-modification/ )
According to the National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration, cloud seeding is the injection of silver iodide into clouds via pyrotechnics. Cloud seeding is meant to create rainfall or snowfall in clouds that otherwise would not produce precipitation. It is a form of weather modification, introduced in the 1940s and 50s.
The Desert Research Institute in Nevada explains that cloud seeding “can be done from ground-based generators or aircraft.”
Long-term exposure to silver iodide may cause argyria, which turns the skin a gray or blue color, according to the CDC. They do not believe this condition to be otherwise harmful.

Is "otherwise" in the sentence mean "If their skin does not turn gray or blue, they do not believe long-term exposure to silver iodide to be harmful." ?
That is,  is "otherwise" in the sentence mean "if their skin does not turn gray or blue" ?
Is "this condition" in the sentence mean "long-term exposure to silver iodide" ?

"Is 'otherwise' in the sentence mean: If their skin do not turn gray or blue..."
Don't forget that 3rd person singular verbs append 's', or here it makes 'does'
Argyria is the condition and, other than the sign of skin tone bluing, no harm is done. Otherwise=in other way.

So, what these sentences mean is that even if they get exposed to artificial rain containing silver iodide, there is nothing wrong with their body. It is just that their skin color changes when they get exposed to artificial rain. But, people do not believe it and believe that getting exposed to artificial rain is harmful?

I corrected the mistake by changing "do" to "does" as you pointed out.

The CDC (Center for Disease Control) does not believe that the condition (argyria) is harmful to people in any other way than turning their skin blue. The sentence says nothing about what people in general believe.
